# Scaling contour plot colors over several orders of magnitude

Tags: plotting, color

I have this contour plot that has values ranging from ~0.01 to ~100, however, there aren't distinct colors between every order of magnitude.  I've tried putting a Log scale on the `ColorFunction`, scaling my data with a Log, and playing with `ColorFunctionScaling`, but none of these got me color distinctions between orders of magnitude.

```
ContourPlot[1/100 E^(x + y), {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}, 
 Contours -> {.01, .1, 1., 10., 100.}, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SiennaTones"]), PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image: <code>ContourPlot</code> output]
In this plot, every order of magnitude is a different color, but the difference is only very slight between 0.01 and 0.1, and still subtle between 0.1 and 1.  I'd like to be able to see all of them distinctly.

Comment: Could you simply plot `Log[f[x,y]]` instead of `f[x,y]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ContourShading` instead of `ColorFunction`:

```
contours = {.01, .1, 1., 10., 100.};
colors = ColorData["SiennaTones"] /@ Subdivide[Length @ contours];

ContourPlot[1/100 E^(x + y), {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}, 
 Contours -> contours, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ContourShading -> colors, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, discretize the `ColorFunction` argument:

```
discretize = Total[UnitStep[# - contours]] / Length[contours]&;

ContourPlot[1/100 E^(x + y), {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}, 
 Contours -> contours, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SiennaTones"][discretize@#]&), 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

An alternative way to discretize the color function argument:

```
ClearAll[pw]
pw[x_]:= Piecewise[Thread[{Subdivide[Length @ contours],
  BlockMap[#[[1]] <= x < #[[2]] &, Join[{0}, contours, {2 Max @ contours}], 2, 1]}], 1]

ContourPlot[1/100 E^(x + y), {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}, 
 Contours -> contours, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SiennaTones"][pw[#]]&), 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]