# The color changes at an interval of orders of magnitude in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, color

If I want to `ArrayPlot` with color changes at an interval of orders of magnitude, how could I do it?

I have an array where some of the values are very small and some of the values are very large, and I want  small values could plot a clear area. In other words, I want 0-10 values of matrix to correspond to 0-0.25 of color,10-100 to 0.25-0.5 and so on. For example the picture as bellow. Color Range from 0-10-100-1000 change continuously.

[image]

[the answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202804/76643) show the way to change discontinuously. But I want to change continuously.

I tried `Rescale` but it doesn't feel practical, a lot of the color is compressed. The following code is just for the sake of explanation, but actually my matrix is so large that the graph looks continuous.

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {50, 50}];
ArrayPlot[a, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][
     Rescale[ Log[#], {0, Log[1000]}, {0, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {50, 50}];
ArrayPlot[a, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"]), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: @xzczd I think it's not. I want 0-10 values of matrix to correspond to 0-0.25 of `color`,10-100 to 0.25-0.5 and so on. I think what he does is change the value of `BarLegend`

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36830/1871

Comment: @xzczd Wow, thank you. I've been looking for it all afternoon and get nothing. w(ﾟДﾟ)w